# Use github website purely - upload to add files

Tags: github

I'm trying to purely use the website Github to create a repo, then public first commit. (Because I cant install the desktop client on this computer, nor use the command line, school restrictions)

I found a little cheat, I clicked the "make readme" button  then renamed that file to make the first commit.

I created a screncast here:
[Youtube :: Use Github without the Desktop App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cRRdFJAT7Bk)

After that I can create new text based files by clicking "+" button and create subdirectories too. But I don't know how to upload image, other text based files, or other non-text files to the repo using just the website. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub's web interface isn't designed as a complete Git solution. It allows you to do a subset of the operations you could do in a local clone, including [just about every part of GitHub Flow](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flow-in-the-browser/).

Their [documentation about adding files](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-new-files/) only covers adding text files using the online editor, which you have already discovered. I don't believe that it supports uploading files.